# IE error: Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

Here is my jQuery code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Lead/GetStatusesPerLeadType",
        type: "POST",
        data: { leadTypeId: $("#LeadTypeID").val() },
        success: function (response) {
            document.getElementById('statusTD').innerHTML = response;
        }
    })
});
```

I encounter the following error in the IE developer tool: `Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference`

If I tell the debugger to continue, the result on the page is OK - the correct data is filled in the selected element, so I don't see why I get this exception.

this is the html:

```
<td><select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field LeadTypeID must be a number." data-val-required="The LeadTypeID field is required." id="LeadTypeID" name="Search.LeadType.LeadTypeID">
<option value="0">Lead 1</option>
<option value="0">Lead 2</option>
</select></td>
<td><select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field StatusID must be a number." data-val-required="The StatusID field is required." id="Search_Status_StatusID" name="Search.Status.StatusID"><option selected="selected" value="0">choose</option>
<option value="22">Duplicate (Set by System)</option>
<option value="23">status 1</option>    
</select></td>
```

Comment: Does "statusTD" exists?
Can you post HTML content?

Comment: can u paste ur HTML, so that we can see where is statusID?

Comment: document.getElementById('statusTD') is returning null or undefined. Check this element definitely is present on the page when the success callback is triggered

Comment: Is the `statusTD` element getting loaded after the ajax request completes? In that case, you might get this error.

Comment: BTW, regarding the code: I see you use `jQuery`. Why not use `$(...)` instead of `getElementById`?

Comment: statusTD is not defined in this html.

Comment: stupid me... i did forget to set the id='statusTD' on the td. thanks!